# Correct way to perform a GET to another PHP file hosted on wordpress

Tags: php, ajax

When performing a GET from inside a .PHP file that is part of a short code is there a way (or a correct way) to reference another PHP file in the same folder

For example I have a shortcode that uses a function in a PHP file and I want to perform the below request where the URL (**$initurl**) is a PHP file also hosted on Wordpress site

```
        const createCheckoutSession = function (stripe) {
            return fetch("' . $initurl . '", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    createCheckoutSession: 1,
                }),
            }).then(function (result) {
                return result.json();
            });
        };
```

Comment: Not adding an answer as I can't really elaborate on it, but have you checked out this page in the WP Docs? https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/making-http-requests/

Comment: If you're making an HTTP GET request then you'd need to pass the full URL, but if the PHP file is in the same folder I don't understand why you'd be making an HTTP request? What are you trying to do? If you just want the contents of the file then you don't need an HTTP request.

Comment: Your example line of code looks like JavaScript, not PHP. Are you making the GET request from JavaScript that's output by the shortcode? If so you should really be using the REST API, rather than sending requests directly to files.

Comment: The use case is that we are trying to implement a Stripe integration and as part of this we create a Stripe checkout session as below - and this contains $initurl that is PHP file

// Create a Checkout Session with the selected product
   const createCheckoutSession = function (stripe) {
    return fetch("' . $initurl . '", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
      createCheckoutSession: 1,
     }),
    }).then(function (result) {
     return result.json();
    });
   };